# Android: why use XMLReader?

Tags: android, xmlreader, saxparser

Is there any reason why I should use a XMLReader with the SAXParser? I'm seeing this kind of usage quite a lot:

```
        sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        LoginContentHandler uch = new LoginContentHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(uch);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
```

I always use the parser this way:

```
        sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler dh = new LoginContentHandler();
        sp.parse(in, dh);
```

Any particular reason? Just wondering because my way is shorter, and I don't really see why I should use a XMLReader.

Comment: Tree vs Event based I believe: http://www.saxproject.org/event.html

Comment: Is SAX not always event based?

Comment: the XMLreader should be loading the file/stream into memory as a tree:

`Finally, it is important to remember that it is possible to construct a parse tree using an event-based API, and it is possible to use an event-based API to traverse an in-memory tree. Have fun!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so to answer the question.

People using XMLReader are assuming that there is enough memory to store the file as a tree object and be able to traverse it at Log(n) time for searching.

On the other hand using SAX straight would mean you are using a event based plugin which would be in n time, but should leave a much less memory foot print.

It's a choice between space and speed.

note the reading about this [from SAX's own page:](http://www.saxproject.org/event.html)